# PHPExcel how to set date format in cell during export so filtration is available?

Tags: phpexcel

I would like to be able to filter my data like this:

```
Year ( + )
     Month ( + )
          Day ( + ).
```

At first i tought it's problem of cell formatting cause the format was set to General. So i did this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('G2:G256')
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode(
                PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2
            );
```

And i worked. Now my cell G2 is formatted as date (at least excel says so). But i'm not able to sort this until i select cell and hit enter, after this ONLY this one cell is sortable. I have no idea why.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the __value__ that you're storing in that cell? Is it a string like `"2015-07-15"` or is it an MS Excel serialized timestamp value? My guess is the former

Comment: I assign it this way $formattedRow[] = date('Y-m-d',$row->user_created); user_created is taken from db and the format is for instance 2015-02-26 so i guess it's a string.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set date values in cells as MS Excel timestamp values, not strings or unix timestamps.

Assuming from the way you're doing it at the moment that `$row->user_created` is a Unix timestamp value the, rather than

```
$formattedRow[] = date('Y-m-d',$row->user_created);
```

use

```
$formattedRow[] = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel(
    $row->user_created
);
```

which will set the value to a MS Excel serialized date/timestamp

You still want to set the number format mask, so that MS Excel knows how the date should be displayed; but as it's stored in Excel format rather than as a string, it will be sortable or filterable, or usable in formulae, etc